# How to make multidimensional array using np.repeat

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array `A = np.array([1.43, 5.12, 2.67])`
I want to make a multidimensional array named B from array A using np.repeat like this

```
B =np.repeat(A, 4)
```

and the result show like this:

```
B = [1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 5.12, 5.12, 5.12, 5.12, 2.67, 2.67, 2.67, 2.67)
```

But i want the result shown like this:

```
B = ([1. 43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43],
[5.12, 5.12, 5.12, 5.12],
[2.67, 2.67, 2.67, 2.67])
```

What should I do to get the result like that?

Comment: Try this : `np.tile(A, (3,1)).T` or `np.repeat(A, 3).reshape(3,-1)`

Comment: You can avoid a copy by broadcasting: `np.broadcast_to(A[:, None], (A.shape[0], 4))`

Comment: If you make `A` a (3,1) shape, you can apply repeat to the last aixs: `np.repeat(A,4, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the output array to achieve the desired format.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1.43, 5.12, 2.67])
B = np.repeat(A, 4).reshape(3, -1)
print(B)
```

Output

```
[[1.43 1.43 1.43 1.43]
 [5.12 5.12 5.12 5.12]
 [2.67 2.67 2.67 2.67]]
```

Comment: I want to ask again. We can call the elements of array B using print(B[0]) for call rows 1 of B. But is it possible for us to call the elements of each line? Because even though the value of each row is the same, each row will be given a different multiplier

Comment: For example, for the first row of B, the first 1.43 will multiplied by 2, and the second 1.43 will multiplied by 3, and the last one will multiplied by 4. is this possible to do? thank you